# swagger-codegen ABAP object nested

Tags: abap, swagger-codegen

I'm currently writing a generator for the ABAP language and I'm facing one problem.
In the service that I have to transform I have the following object:

```
 "router_options": {
  "track": true,
  "motorway": true,
  "toll": true,
  "trailers": 0,
  "weight": 0,
  "weight_per_axle": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "width": 0,
  "length": 0,
  "hazardous_goods": "explosive",
  "max_walk_distance": 0,
  "approach": "unrestricted",
  "snap": 0,
  "strict_restriction": true
}
```

when I execute the codegen generator the code generated give me the following code

```
i_router_options_track      type bool  optional       
i_router_options_motorway      type bool  optional       
i_router_options_toll      type bool  optional      
i_router_options_trailers      type int  optional      
i_router_options_weight      type float  optional       
i_router_options_weight_per_axle      type float  optional  
i_router_options_height      type float  optional    
i_router_options_width      type float  optional    
i_router_options_length      type float  optional   
i_router_options_hazardous_goods      type string  optional 
i_router_options_max_walk_distance      type float  optional
```

The approach would be more something like declaring a type of structure in the operation part like that

```
types : begin of ts_router_options, 
    track              type bool,
    motorway           type bool,
    toll               type bool,
    trailers           type int,
    weight             type float,
    weight_per_axle    type float,
    height             type float,
    width              type float,
    length             type float,
    hazardous_goods    type string,
    max_walk_distance  type float,
    approach           type string,
    snap               type float,
    strict_restriction type bool,
    end of ts_router_options.
```

and use it like below :

```
data : router_options type ts_router_options.
router_options-height = '10,10'
```

Does anyone can help me for that ?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I don't know swagger but it looks like it generates input parameters for a method/function module. You cannot have optional fields in a structured type.

Comment: Saw that you [also posted this as an issue in ˋswagger-codegenˋ](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7643). I assume you have trouble producing the ˋtypes: begin of ... end of ...ˋ from your swagger input file, right? We’ll be glad to help, but you need to provide us with more context - maybe your Swagger sample input file and a link to your GitHub repo?